# How to read counts into 1D array?

Tags: fortran

My goal is to put each bin (bin1,bin2,bin3, etc...) into an array of 1 dimension. I understand my if statements are copious and I need to learn how to make it look more efficient. I'd like to read each bin which counts number of occurrences in each column of a range of numbers into a 1D array. For example, have the counts in bin1 read into one array, while bin2 reads into a separate array, etc. I have looked around and I can't find anything similar to what I need to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Right now I only have if statements to read into the first 3 bins. Thank you guys! Here is my code:

```
        program test
        implicit none
    
    
        real a, b, c, d, e 
        integer i)
            
        integer bin1, bin2, bin3, bin4, bin5, bin6, bin7, bin8, bin9
        integer bin10
        
        
        
        bin1=0
        bin2=0
        bin3=0
        bin4=0
        bin5=0
        bin6=0
        bin7=0
        bin8=0
        bin9=0
        bin10=0
        
        

        open(unit = 7, file="test.dat")
        do i=1, 10
            read(7,*) a, b, c, d, e 
            
            if(a>=-1 .AND. a<-.8)then
            bin1=bin1+1
            end if 
            
            if(b>=-1 .AND. b<-.8)then 
            bin1=bin1+1
            end if
            
            if(c>=-1 .AND. c<-.8)then 
            bin1=bin1+1
            end if
            
            if(d>=-1 .AND. d<-.8)then 
            bin1=bin1+1
            end if
            
            if(e>=-1 .AND. e<-.8)then 
            bin1=bin1+1
            end if
            
            if(a>=-.8 .AND. a<-.6)then
            bin2=bin2+1
            end if 
            
            if(b>=-.8 .AND. b<-.6)then 
            bin2=bin2+1
            end if
            
            if(c>=-.8 .AND. c<-.6)then 
            bin2=bin2+1
            end if
            
            if(d>=-.8 .AND. d<-.6)then 
            bin2=bin2+1
            end if
            
            if(e>=-.8 .AND. e<-.6)then 
            bin2=bin2+1
            end if
            if(a>=-.6 .AND. a<-.4)then
            bin3=bin3+1
            end if 
            
            if(b>=-.6 .AND. b<-.4)then 
            bin3=bin3+1
            end if
            
            if(c>=-.6 .AND. c<-.4)then 
            bin3=bin3+1
            end if
            
            if(d>=-.6 .AND. d<-.4)then 
            bin3=bin3+1
            end if
            
            if(e>=-.6 .AND. e<-.4)then 
            bin3=bin3+1
            end if
            
            
            
            
            
            
        end do
            
            
        close(7)
    
        open(unit = 8, file="result.dat")
        write(8,*) bin1, bin2, bin3
            
        close(8)
    
        end program
```

I have researched the count function of an array, but I don't want to put the values of the numbers themselves into an array. I just want to count the instances of a number in a range and place it into a bin, and have that bin's count value stored into an array.

Edit: This program originally was a test program to see if I could count numbers in a specific range. Now I am making a program to do the same thing, but for 4 different columns separately (20 bins for each column b,c,d,e.) So, for column b I want 20 bins with the complete bin range going from (-3 to 3). For example, bin1 for column b will count how many numbers in that column are in the range (-3 to -2.7), bin2 would count for the range (-2.7, -2.4), etc.. I want the bin width and each bin range to be the same for each column so that each column is counted for the same ranges. Originally, I had a horribly inefficient program (which worked) but in the end I had 80 if statements (20 for each column.) I wanted to see if I could use arrays and the count function to reduce it to just 4 lines. I have seen suggestions in the comments to have an array which looks like:

```
        binb(i)=binb(i)+count(b>=lower(i) .and. b<upper(i))
        binc(i)=binc(i)+count(c>=lower(i) .and. c<upper(i))
        bind(i)=bind(i)+count(d>=lower(i) .and. d<upper(i))
        bine(i)=bine(i)+count(e>=lower(i) .and. e<upper(I))
```

but lower and upper must be arrays instead of scalars...
Here is my program thus far:

```
    program mean_analysis
    implicit none
    
    integer i, j, k, N, l
    double precision a, b, c, d, e
    integer binb(1:20),binc(1:20),bind(1:20),bine(1:20)
    real lower(1:20),upper(1:20)

    

    character(100) event
    
    upper(1)=-2.7
    lower(1)=-3
    

    




    
        
    open(unit = 7, file="zpc_initial_momenta.dat")
        do l=2,20
            lower(l)=lower(l-1)+.3
            upper(l)=upper(l-1)+.3  
        end do
        
        do k=1, 10
            read(7,'(A)') event
            do j=1,4000
            read(7,*) a, b, c, d, e
            do i=1,20
        binb(i)=binb(i)+count(b>=lower(i:) .and. b<upper(:i))
        binc(i)=binc(i)+count(c>=lower(i:) .and. c<upper(:i))
        bind(i)=bind(i)+count(d>=lower(i:) .and. d<upper(:i))
        bine(i)=bine(i)+count(e>=lower(i:) .and. e<upper(:i))   
        
        end do
        end do
        end do
                
    close(7)
            
    open(unit = 8, file="outputanalysis.dat")
        Write(8,*) 'The bins in each column are as follows:'
        Write(8,*) 'FIRST COLUMN (MOMENTUM IN X DIRECTION)'
        write(8,*) binb
        
    close(8)
    
    end program
```

I have tried to remedy the lower - upper scalar issue by implementing an idea someone had on another post of mine, to make lower-> lower(I:) and upper -> upper(:I) , but it does not use the correct i-th values for the upper and lower arrays that I defined earlier with a do loop. Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You really _do_ want to be using arrays. When you have variables `x1`, `x2`, ... `xn` and lots of ifs, that's usually a sign that an array should be used.

Comment: You mean using arrays to store the values themselves? @francescalus

Comment: Instead of `bin1`, `bin2`,... create just one array `bin(1:10)`.

Comment: What does the colon mean? That isn't the same as a matrix array, is it? How would I save each count into each bin using that one array?

Comment: https://fortran-lang.org/en/learn/

Comment: @francescalus What do you think the best way would be to reduce the number of if statements? How would using arrays help alleviate this?

Comment: Starting with `read(7,*) a(1:5)` and following with a `bin(1)=bin(1)+count(a>=-1.and.a<-.8)` immediately removes four of them. Then one moves on to something with `bin(i)=bin(i)+count(a>=lower(i).and.i<upper(i))` before something even more exotic with `bin(:)=...` if one wants to get fancy.

Comment: @francescalus Sorry to summon you again... Say I want each column to be counted separately: for example, 10 bins for column 1, 10 for column 2, etc.. all with the same range parameters (from -1 to 1). Would this make it any more efficient? I'd need 20 different arrays (for each column, one for each range [-1 to -.8],[-.8 to -.6], etc...) So, in the end, I'd end up with bin(1)=bin(1)+count(b>=-1 .and b<-.8), which I'd have to repeat for each bin, right?

Comment: If you [edit] your question to include progress you've made then we'll have better context. Comments don't work well to read or respond to such updates.

Comment: There, I have updated the question: my apologies!

Comment: Please do not put any of "Updated", "Edited" or "Solved", the less something like **EDITED, PLEASE READ**. Into the title. This site has a revision tracking system. Everyone can see there has been an edit. An edit also bumps the question to the top.

Comment: Also greetings like "Good afternoon, Good morning, Good evening" make very little sense on a global site and are to be deleted. Many will also edit out the superficial Thank you at the and.